# Does anybody know which is the general solution of this differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have to find the general solution for the following initial value problem: 
$
\left.
\begin{eqnarray}
u_t+div(a\cdot u)=0, (t,x)\in(0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^d\atop
u(0,x)=u_0(x), x\in\mathbb{R}^d, a\in\mathbb{R}^d
\end{eqnarray}
\right\}
$

I've working on the one dimensional case and I have found by the method of characteristics that the solution is $u(t,x)=u_0(x-at)$. How can I generalize this?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have you **worked** on the case $d=1$ for example ?

Comment: Yeah, i'm new posting in mathexhange, i'll put the information that i've found in the description

Comment: Your notation is confusing. $a \cdot u$ implies that $u$ is a vector. This would mean $a \cdot u$ is a scalar (which you can't take the divergence of). Yet $u_t \propto \text{div} (a \cdot u) $ implies that $u$ is a scalar. Are you sure you've written the correct generalization? I am guessing you want $\textbf{u}_t = -\nabla \cdot [\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{u}]$ where $\textbf{a}$ is a tensor and $\textbf{u}$ is a vector? Or maybe the simpler $u_t = -\nabla \cdot \textbf{A} u$ where $A$ is a vector function of the spatial coordinates? Probably this is what you want . . .

Comment: @kevinkayaks : The dot denotes in fact the ordinary product of scalar-valued function $u(...)$ and vector $a$. Besides, the asker should have a look at the answer by Mike to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856479/305862).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing what you meant to write is the higher dimensional advection equation with a constant velocity $\textbf{a}$:
$$ u_t(\textbf{x},t) = - \nabla \cdot \textbf{a} u(\textbf{x},t).$$
You can separate variables:
$$u = \prod_i U_i(x_i,t),$$
giving
$$\sum_i \partial_t U_i(x_i,t)\prod_{j\neq i}U_j(x_j,t) = -\sum_i \partial_{x_i} a_i U_i(x_i,t)\prod_{j\neq i}U_j(x_j,t),$$
or rearranging,
$$ \sum_i \Big[\partial_t U_i(x_i,t) + \partial_{x_i}a_i U_i(x_i,t)\Big] = 0.$$
This means each separated component satisfies the 1D problem:
$$ \partial_t U_i(x_i,t) + \partial_{x_i}a_i U_i(x_i,t) = 0.$$
That is, $U_i(x_i,t) = U_{i,0}(x_i-a_i t)$.
Therefore the general solution to your problem is
$$u(\textbf{x},t) = \prod_i U_{i,0}(x_i-a_i t),$$
i.e.
$$ u = u_0(\textbf{x}-\textbf{a} t).$$